# Is there any function in C which can store memory address of an array to a variable? What type of variable will store this address?

Tags: c

I used the following code to do the same. Is this the correct way to do the same?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int ar[512]={0};
    char hex[100]="0xf";
    sscanf(hex,"%x",&ar);
    printf("\n%s",hex);
}
```

Basicly I need to store this hexadecimal value into a variable as a string.

Comment: Do you mean`&`?

Comment: Your question isn't particularly clear. An array (e.g. `int ar[512]` can decay to a pointer to the first element (e.g. `int *arp = ar;` will result in pointer `arp` such that `arp == &ar[0]`). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: ar is also a pointer to this array @nanofarad

Comment: `ar` is an array. When used in a pointer context, it will *decay* to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

i believe you can make a pointer pointing to the start of the array and print the address of the pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    // my array
    int a[2];
    //my pointer pointing to the start of my array
    int *mysillypointer = &a;
    //print the addres of my pointer
    //the pointer is the "variable " that has the address of your array
    printf("Address of array a is : %p\n",mysillypointer);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, but my question is different. I need to store this hexadecimal value into a variable so that I can change this hexadecimal value to a bit array.

Comment: I dont understand your question it is stored inside the pointer , if you want it in an array you can do this.
char hex[sizeof(mysillypointer)];
itoa (mysillypointer,hex,16);
now its in array hex and process it from there, you can also edit the address inside the pointer by normal operations + / - or even copy it elsewhere